# Make Rhodecode display flat list of repos instead of the common grouped view

Tags: rhodecode

By default Rhodecode lists the repos available to a user in a grouped form - root-level repos first in a list and a list of groups underneath. Clicking on a group displays the nested repos and groups in a similar list with the selected group becoming the new "root".
Is it possible to configure Rhodecode to display a "flat" list of all repos available to a user, prefixed with a "path" made of groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A flat list of repositories with groups is displayed in /_admin/repos but for performance reasons a flat list is not allowed in main view.

You can use for reference the /_admin/repos instead.